# Is there a way to combine these two ping commands?

Tags: windows, ping

There are two methods of seeing outputs of continuous ping test.

1. `ping a.b.c.d -t > output_filename.txt`
2. `ping a.b.c.d -t` (live results visible on screen)

Is there a way to combine the two methods?

If the above is possible, is it possible to  also capture the timestamps all the way?

or

To capture only the time stamp when the details of the results change? eg. time=1ms and time>1ms to show their time stamp?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, Can you please include which OS or Application your using to send the ping command? OSX, Bash, Windows, IOS, ect...

Comment: It is windows, though you have to know the specifics of the `-t` part in combination with the description.  (On most systems: ` -t` means: `Specify a timeout, in seconds, before ping exits regardless of how many packets have been received.` On windows it means `continious pings`, which matches the OP's question

Answer (score 4):

On **Windows** you can accomplish this with **PowerShell**:

`ping google.com -t | Tee-Object ping.txt`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a simple **command prompt** in **Windows**, you can run two commands, one after the other by separating them with `&`. This however will not run them simultaneously.

> ping a.b.c.d -t & ping a.b.c.d -t > output_file.txt

The first command would run visually in the Command Prompt window until <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is pressed. The second command would then begin, writing to the output file, until <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is pressed *again*.

---

Source: [How to run two commands in one line in Windows CMD? (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8055430/2096457)

Comment: If he used the `-t` in the first half as indicated it would never run the 2nd command, or did I miss something?

Comment: @50-3 I updated my answer explaining the behavior.

Comment: still need the `-t` otherwise it will send 4 requests then move to the next command. Sorry just nit picking

Comment: @50-3 I must not be awake these last couple days XD I edited it

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use the tee command in linux:

```
ping a.b.c.d -t 60 | tee output_filename.txt
```

This will allow you to write to the file and view the output on your screen.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is for windows CMD only**

Syntax used:

> start dualping.bat a.b.c.d & ping a.b.c.d -t

Batch file code:

```
@echo off
Echo "This window is running a batch to ping %1 and output to a text file"
ping %1 -t > output.txt
```

---

This will open a new CMD window with the message "This window is running a batch to ping `%1` and output to a text file" where `%1` is the address passed into the bat file.

You minimize that window and you will have `ping a.b.c.d -t` running in the window you first setup